# Do we have any constant to get the Current User path in NSIS

Tags: windows, installation, constants, nsis

I am new to NSIS scripting. I need to delete a folder from 
`C:\Users\{USER NAME}`. 
Is there any constant to get this path. My application is present in user folder. `$DOCUMENTS`, `$DESKTOP` are not helpful for me

Comment: Vote up: I don't know why this question was voted down. Is far more productive to type a query on the Web than searching a very limited HTML help document. Btw, the help says "A typical path is C:\Documents and Settings\Foo" which does mean nothing nowadays since every new release someone at M$ wants to move folders around...

Answer (score 1):

For Windows 2000 (and later), NSIS provides the `$PROFILE` constant (see [documentation](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#varconstant)). As far as I know, any Windows environmental variable should work as well (e.g. `%UserProfile%`), but I'd stick to the NSIS provided constants where available.